# How to change "24-Jun-2012" to "24-06-2012" using date format

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I am trying to convert "12-Jun-2013" date to " 12-06-2013" but its giving me exception.

```
String req="12-Jun-2013"

SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy",Locale.UK);
             try {
                Date date = (Date) sdfSource.parse(req);
                 SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.UK);
                 req = sdfDestination.format(date);
                 System.out.println("final object"+req);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am getting exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12-Jun-2013"
```

Comment: Your input format doesn't match your input; it should be `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Comment: @Vulcan You should probably post it as an answer.

Comment: @Amber I don't believe that simple answers like that deserve rep, and I've got a (bad?) habit of posting in a comment rather than a community wiki answer. (copied from another comment of mine in a similar situation)

Comment: The output format doesn't match the requirements either...

Comment: I changed the format still same exception is coming both the input and output.

Comment: @Valcan, I don't think it is only about rep. Answer should be accepted also and as a comment it wont.

Comment: @Jaydeep That's the bad habit part of it :P Regardless, my answer would not have been sufficient since I didn't notice that the output format doesn't fulfill the requirement either. Michael's answer is better than mine would have been.

Comment: @Vulcan I'd say don't worry about rep and just worry about posting good answers. That's the policy I go by.

Answer (score 11):

your source `SimpleDateFormat` should be

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy",
                Locale.UK);
```

and your Destination `SimpleDateFormat` should be

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.UK);
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy",Locale.UK);SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.UK);

Comment: after trying as per you also i am getting same exception

Comment: @user2515032 If that's your code there, you didn't correctly copy-paste this answer.

Comment: @user2515032 in your `sdSource` replace `/` with `-`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
    String req = "12-Jun-2013"; 
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM-yyyy", Locale.UK).parse(req);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.UK);
        req = sdfDestination.format(date);
        System.out.println("final object" + req);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem